# What is the difference between $dP_X$, $P[X \in dx]$, and $P_X[dx]$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

It appears that these notations are equivalent when referring to the measure with which a function $f(x)$ is integrated with respect to. It seems to me that the expression $\int f dP_X$ is very clear once some measure theory is learned. In what contexts are the other notations useful or necessary?

Comment: What is $X$ in your notation? Integral with respect to measure $\mu$, usually is written $\int_\Omega f d \mu$ or $\int_\Omega f(x) d \mu(x)$ (Halmos)

Comment: I am sorry, $X$ is a random variable and the measure here is $P_X :=P \circ X^{-1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\mu(dy)$ notation is useful when you integrate with respect to a measure $\kappa(x, \cdot)$ on $Y$ that varies with a parameter $x$. E.g. conditional probability or something like
$$f(x) = \int_{Y} g(y) \kappa(x, dy).$$

The $P(X \in dx)$ is helpful because it makes certain formulas valid for arbitrary random variables look similar to corresponding ones for discrete random variables. E.g. $$E(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}x P(X \in dx).$$

Comment: Why is it $X\in dx$ rather than e.g. $X\in[x,\,x+dx]$?

Comment: @J.G. I think it is some kind of a shorthand for that. It is supposed to be syntactically similar to $P(X = x)$ when $X$ is discrete, so I guess the brevity is good.