# Integrating w.r.t. to $\mathrm d\mu(x)$ vs $\mu(\mathrm dx)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, notation

When integrating a function $f$ with respect to a measure $\mu$, I often see two different notations
$$ \int_A f(x) \mathrm d\mu(x) $$
and
$$ \int_A f(x) \mu(\mathrm dx) $$

How are these two different? Is it just a notational convention or are there technical differences between them?

I believe, I saw occurrences of the second version mostly in the context of probability theory. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4414050) seems to suggest that both are equal at least for probability measures. Is this always true?

Comment: they are exactly the same thing.